# Visual Studio Web Package - doesn't appear to create full Application

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7, web-deployment, msdeploy

I've got a .Net 4 ASP.Net application developed with VS 2012.  I'm publishing the app with a publish profile set to create a Web Deploy Package, which I'll be copying over and creating on a Win2008 IIS7.3 server.

When I run the deployment script, server-side, with a "/Y" parameter, it appears to work correctly.

```
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
-source:package='C:\ReconTool\test\deploy\ReconTool.Presentation.Web.zip"
-dest:auto,includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-setParamFile:"C:\ReconTool\test\deploy\ReconTool.Presentation.Web.SetParameters.xml"

Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Info: Creating application (Default Web Site/ReconToolTest)
Info: Adding virtual path (Default Web Site/ReconToolTest)
...
```

But the new web site doesn't run for me - I get an 403.18 - forbidden error.  When I look in inetmgr on the server for the new app, I only see the 'IIS' config section, where applications I've created manually have an 'ASP.Net' and the 'IIS' config sections.

It appears like it's not creating a full application, there are no error pages, etc, that are configured in the ASP.Net section.  Wierd thing is I see the new app via appcmd as an application:

```
APP "Default Web Site/" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)
APP "Default Web Site/ReconToolDev" (applicationPool:ReconToolDevPool)
APP "Default Web Site/ReconToolTest" (applicationPool:ReconToolTestPool )
```

Both the Dev and Test application pools appear to be exactly the same, from what I can tell. The web.config in my Dev and Test applications are identical.

I'd appreciate any advice on additional steps I need to deploy an Visual Studio project and get it to config as an application in IIS.

Corey.

Comment: Did you try not specifying the `-disableLink:AppPoolExtension `

Comment: Tried it - no difference.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: And the contentextension? the contentextension governs virtual directories...

Comment: No difference as well. In any case, I'd really hate to have to hand edit the VS-generated script every time I deploy.  Easy to forget ;)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942037